# Align and spacing in a direction flex

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello i have a bar app

```
 <AppBar position="sticky" className={classes.appBar} >
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Toolbar className={classes.root}>
        <Typography noWrap>
        <img src={require("./nodejs-icon.svg")} alt="bug" height={100} />
          </Typography>
              <SearchIcon color="secondary" />
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          {auth && (
            <div>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMenu}
                color="secondary"
              >
                <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon  style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
```

and I have the following css setting:

```
const headerStyle = (muiBaseTheme => ({
  root:{
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    background: "#fff",
    }, 
    appBar:{
      background: "#fff",
      boxShadow:
      "0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)",
    },
    flexEnd:{
      alignItems: 'flex-end'
    },
    flexStart:{
      alignItems: 'flex-start'
    },
    flexCenter:{
      alignItems: 'center'
    }
}))
```

I declared my tool bar with fex display
and would like to align items and create spacing

i need the image in the beginning

the input in the center

and the icon at the end

but I don't know how I could do that

could someone help me how can i do this responsively?

[image]

Comment: can you share code in sandbox?

Comment: @yes i go put here

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar here : https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-hill-nwgp1

Comment: code isn't working properly, fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS `justify-content: space-between;` to your `Toolbar` element, since it is the parent of the element you wanted to align, and that should do the job. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content). This is a sample I made, you should be able to get it.

```css
.appbar,
.container,
.toolbar{
  width: 100%;
}

.toolbar{
  display: flex;
  /* Answer you need*/
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.toolbar > div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}

.toolbar > div:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
}
.toolbar > div:nth-child(2){
  background:yellow;
}
.toolbar > div:nth-child(3){
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="appbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Friend

What if my div didn't have a text but an icon like I could align it in the center?

Comment: @Felipe yeah, the alignment is not base on the text but on the element. So it should take effect. Just remember that `display:flex` only works to it's direct child or first degree child. So the `flex` property should always be assigned to the immediate parent of the element you want to align. So on your code, since we place the `justify-content` in the `Toolbar` element, the elements that will be aligned are the icons you wanted. Just in addition, I would recomend that you wrapped your `SearchIcon` and `Input` element in one `div` so they can be wrapped as one in the middle.